# Access elements of data types

Tags: isabelle, isar

Is it possible in Isabelle to access the individual elements of a data type? Let's say I have the following data type:

```
datatype foo = mat int int int int
```

and (e.g. in a lemma)

```
fixes A :: foo
```

Is it possible to access the single elements of A? Or alternatively, fix the single elements (`fix a b c d :: int`) and then define `A` as `mat a b c d`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively it is possible to define custom extractor functions when specifying a data type. In your case, for example

```
datatype foo = Mat (mat_a : int) (mat_b : int) (mat_c : int) (mat_d : int)
```

would work.

Then you can access the first element of a `foo` value `x` by `mat_a x`, the second by `mat_b x`, and so on.

**Example:**

```
 value "mat_a (Mat 1 2 3 4)"
```

> "1"  :: "int"

Answer (score 1):

On a logical level, you can use the `case` syntax to deconstruct the datatype (i.e. `case A of mat a b c d ⇒ …`). You can also define your own projection functions using `fun` or `primrec`, e.g.

```
primrec foo1 where "foo1 (mat a b c d) = a"
```

In a proof, you can access the values using `obtain` and the `cases` command, e.g.

```
obtain a b c d where "A = mat a b c d" by (cases A) auto
```

As for your questions about definitions, you can make local definitions in Isar proofs like this:

```
define A where "A = mat a b c d"
```

and you can then unfold that definition using the theorem `A_def`.

If you want to use your definition in the premises or goal already (and have it unfolded in the theorem after proving it), you can use `defines`:

```
lemma
  defines "A ≡ mat a b c d"
  shows   …
```

Again, this gives you a fact `A_def` that you can use to unfold the definition.

You can also use `let ?A = mat a b c d` or pattern matching with `is` to introduce abbreviations. In contrast to the definitions from before, these are only on the syntactic level, i.e. you type `?A`, but after parsing, you have `mat a b c d`, and you will also see `mat a b c d` in the output. `is` works like this:

```
lemma
  shows "P (mat a b c d)" (is "P ?A")
proof -
  term ?A
```

It also works after "assumes".

Comment: Is it also possible to define A in the lemma/theorem itself (i.e. before the proof)?

Comment: I extended my answer accordingly.